# Identify users from smartphone and tablet and hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tablet

I have this layout with drag n drop upload on the left side.

[image: Drag n drop]

My website is responsive but some tablets in landscape mode are large as computer screens. Smartphones and tablets can not upload images with drag n drop (which you see on the left side of the picture).

What I want to do is identify if the user visits my site from a tablet or smartphone. If it does, I want to hide the drag n drop feature and display only the upload button. But if the user is using a computer (even with small screen) I want drag n drop to be possible/visible.

Do not know which technology is required but my site uses HTML, CSS, JavaScript (jQuery) and PHP.

Comment: Get more details here-  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: Have you seen [**What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3514784/1407478)??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using php . There are some classes like mobile detect which detect devices on bases of request header received.